# c# execute methode in data object

Tags: c#

I've seen this problem reported many times, but in my code I don't understand what needs to be changed.

> SelectTeam() is the method that returns me the error in the builder.
>
> The error "Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type" is in the EPlayers constructor.

```
Dictionary<ulong, EPlayers> ePlayers = new Dictionary<ulong, EPlayers>(); 

void LoadData()
{
    ePlayers = Interface.Oxide.DataFileSystem.ReadObject<Dictionary<ulong, EPlayers>>("cEvent/Players");
}        

void SaveData()
{
    Interface.Oxide.DataFileSystem.WriteObject("cEvent/Players", ePlayers);
} 

public class EPlayers
{
    public int team;
    public EPlayers(){}
    internal EPlayers(cEvent cEvent)
    {
        team = SelectTeam();                
    }
}        

void Loaded()
{
    LoadData();
    ePlayers.Add(player.userID, new EPlayers(this){});                    
    SaveData();             
}    

public bool DataPlayersEmpty()
{
    if (Interface.Oxide.DataFileSystem.ExistsDatafile("cEvent/Players"))
    {
        LoadData();
        if(ePlayers.Count() == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} 

public int SelectTeam()
{
    LoadData();
    if(!DataPlayersEmpty())
    {
        int i = 0;
        if(CountTeam(1) <= CountTeam(2))
            return 1;
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
} 

public int CountTeam(int t)
{
    LoadData();
    if(!DataPlayersEmpty())
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var x in ePlayers.Where(x => ((EPlayers)x.Value).team == t))
        {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What should I put in static?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `cEvent cEvent` from `internal EPlayers(cEvent cEvent)` constructor and or do `internal EPlayers(cEvent cvvent)` if `cEvent` is the class... What is `new EPlayers(this){}` this specifically... I would hope and assume it would be the type of `cEvent` because that's what it would take.

Comment: Initially I wanted to add the method here "new EPlayers(this){} " But I didn't have the error message in the console. So I put it in the class to see the info. 

So I did that "internal EPlayers(){team = SelectTeam();}" and "ePlayers.Add(player.userID, new EPlayers());" But always the error.

Comment: change `team = SelectTeam()` to `team = cEvent.SelectTeam()`. You already passed the parameter, you just didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
public class EPlayers
{
    public int team;
    public EPlayers(){}
    internal EPlayers(int selectedTeam)
    {
        this.team = selectedTeam;                
    }
}        

void Loaded()
{
    LoadData();
    ePlayers.Add(player.userID, new EPlayers(SelectTeam()){});                    
    SaveData();             
}
```

Instead of passing the whole `cEvent` while needing only the return value of `SelectTeam()`, we pass that value instead to `EPlayers` constructor.